# Print combined string columns without creating new column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using pandas 0.18. I've got a dataframe that looks like this:

```
>> df = pd.DataFrame({'ods': {0: 'A86016', 1: 'L81042', 2: 'C84013', 3: 'G82228', 4: 'C81083'}, 
                   'id': {0: np.nan, 1: 463061.0, 2: np.nan, 3: 462941.0, 4: np.nan}, 
                   'provider': {0: 'emis', 1: np.nan, 2: 'tpp', 3: 'emis', 4: 'tpp'}})
>> print df
         id     ods provider
0       NaN  A86016     emis
1  463061.0  L81042      NaN
2       NaN  C84013      tpp
3  462941.0  G82228     emis
4       NaN  C81083      tp
```

I'd like to output a table that is formatted like this:

```
 id (ods)   provider
 1 (A86016)     emis
 2 (L81042)      NaN
 3 (C84013)      tpp
```

Is there a simple way to do this with pandas without creating a new column? I know I can do it with something like this:

```
df['newcol'] = df.id.str + " (" + df.ods.str + ")"
print df[['newcol', 'provider']]
```

But I just wondered if I could skip the intermediate step of creating a new column.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is create new `DataFrame` from `Series` - one is concanecated columns `id` and `ods` and other is column `provider`:

```
print pd.DataFrame({'id (ods)': df.id.astype(str) + "(" + df.ods  + ")", 
                    'provider': df.provider})

            id (ods) provider
0       nan (A86016)     emis
1  463061.0 (L81042)      NaN
2       nan (C84013)      tpp
3  462941.0 (G82228)     emis
4       nan (C81083)      tpp
```

Answer (score 0):

you may try to do it this way:

```
df = df.assign(id_obs=df['id'].astype(str) + ' (' + df['ods'] + ')').drop(['id','ods'], axis=1)
```

Timing on 10K DF:

```
In [132]: %timeit pd.DataFrame({'id (ods)':df.id.astype(str) + " (" + df.ods  + ")", 'provider': df.provider})
1 loop, best of 3: 734 ms per loop

In [133]: %timeit df.assign(id_obs=df['id'].astype(str) + ' (' + df['ods'] + ')').drop(['id','ods'], axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 758 ms per loop
```